# Tomcat - not shutting down properly - vjava.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor - macbook

Tags: macos, tomcat10

I am unable to showdown the Tomcat server successfully - getting the below

```
SEVERE: Error stopping Catalina
java.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:552)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:475)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:692)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
```

Comment: Is the Tomcat process still running (check for a `java` process)?

Comment: Hi Piotr - Please guide me here as I am new to Linux - also I had installed Tomcat almost all the new and old versions and I am getting the same error - When I start the tomcat it gets started - but when I try to shutdown it is throwing this error - Please help